# Select specific Twitter in Gwibber without seeing the rest i follow

Tags: 11.04, gwibber

How can i configure Gwibber to show me only 1 Twitter of the group i follow. For example i wish to see a specific one of them without having to see all of the ones i am following.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is possible.

To do that, first login to Twitter.com and [create a Twitter list](https://support.twitter.com/entries/76460-how-to-use-twitter-lists) and add the people you want to have in that list.

Once you've done that, open up Gwibber, and load the "lists" view.

[image]

Then, select a list

[image]

And you're done!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to see all the tweets from only one person? If that's it, click the image next to their name like this:

[image]

That will show you only that person's tweets. To get back to the main view, click the house icon at the top left.